# Não repetir letras (char) numa matriz ASCII

Tags: java, matriz, random

Tinha que criar uma matriz 5x5 imprimindo caracteres aleatórios da tabela ASCII.

```
public class ExercicioClass01g {
    static Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static char mat[][] = new char[5][5];

    public static void gera(int lin, int col){
        Random gerador = new Random();
        int ctlin,ctcol;
        for(ctlin=0;ctlin<lin;ctlin++)
            for(ctcol=0;ctcol<col;ctcol++)
                mat[ctlin][ctcol]=(char)(gerador.nextInt(25)+65);

    }   

    public static void exibe(int lin, int col){
        int ctlin,ctcol;
        for(ctlin=0;ctlin<lin;ctlin++){
            for(ctcol=0;ctcol<col;ctcol++)
                System.out.print(mat[ctlin][ctcol]+" ");
            System.out.println();
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gera(5, 5);
        exibe(5,5);
    }
```

Consegui imprimir mas não consigo fazer as letras (`char`) não se repetirem na matriz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao invés de usar a geração aleatório use o algoritmo [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Seria legal criar uma função que faça a criação da lista e depois use como quiser:

```
public static List<Integer> randomNumbers(int start, int end, int count) {
    List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>(end - start + 1);
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) lista.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(lista);
    lista = lista.subList(0, count);
    return lista;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1NseRG). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/aynufkzq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/ShuffleLetters.java).

Comment: Muito obrigada, funcionou :D

Comment: @FrancineStivanin Dê uma olhada no [tour] Você pode aceitar a resposta e pode votar nela e em quaisquer outras postagens do site também.